# Does the library/sdk support a "hold to talk" mode?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

My application requires that the user be allowed to record their utterance "offline", which is done while their holding down a button, and then I forward the utterance to the assistant. As opposed to just streaming the mic to the service.

Is this mode supported?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and almost out of the box. The library/sdk can work with audio file, so you just need to record your voice offline with a "hold to talk" code and send it to assistant just after.